# Command puts in expect doesn't show the message in the order it should

Tags: linux, scripting, expect

I have a some scripts to automate a process and I want the message about which step I am in it shows in the command window. A piece of code I have is:

```
puts "** Creation of $VMNAME on $HOST begins... **"
spawn ssh -l $USER $HOST
expect_after eof {exit 0}
set timeout 10

expect "(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "password:" { send "$PASSWORD\r" }
expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }
set timeout 1200

puts "** Transferring rhelvm img file to the $HOST... **"
expect "~]#" { send "scp  somelink/rhelvm-0-vol.img /storage/iso/\r" }
expect "Password:" { send "$TESTEMSPASS\r" }

puts "** Transferring the VM conf from $TESTEMSUSER to $HOST... **"
expect "~]#" { send "scp somelink/$VMNAME.conf /root\r" }
expect "Password:" { send "$TESTEMSPASS\r" }

puts "** Removing the $VMNAME... **"
expect "~]#" { send "/opt/ccm/bin/vmremove -f /root/$VMNAME.conf --force\r" }
sleep 10
expect "~]#" { send "rm -rf /storage/vmpool/*.img\r" }
sleep 10

puts "** Creating the $VMNAME... **"
expect "~]#" { send "/opt/ccm/bin/vmcreate -f /root/$VMNAME.conf -g  /storage/iso/rhelvm-0-vol.img -e\r" }
sleep 10

puts "** Starting the $VMNAME ... **"
expect "~]#" { send "virsh start $VMNAME\r" }
sleep 10

expect "~]#" { send "virsh list --all\r"}

expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }

puts "** Creation of $VMNAME is completed. **"
expect "~]#" { send "exit\r" }
```

but what I get in the output is not in this order for example it shows the message of creating the VM but then runs the rm -rf /storage/vmpool/*.img command. 
I tried puts with -nonewline and send_user but nothing seems to work. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Upon the `send "cmd\r"`, `expec`t sends that `send<CR>` to the master side of the pseudo-terminal device that controls the ssh process.

Then `ssh` reads a `cmd<LF>` from the slave side which it sends to the remote host, where it eventually makes its way to a shell there which reads it again.

The shell or the line discipline of the remote pseudo-terminal device sends back a `cmd<CR><LF>` for display (the `echo` of the text that is virtually typed) and that eventually makes it back to the master side of the pseudo-terminal which `expect` uses to control `ssh`.

But `expect` only processes that (the output of `ssh` which includes the `echo`) upon the `expect` directives. So in

```
send "cmd\r"
sleep 4
puts "text"
expect "output of ssh" {...}
```

The `text` is output *before* the *echo* of `cmd`, because that *echo* is only displayed upon the `expect`.

You could do it as:

```
send "cmd\r"
expect "cmd\r\n" # wait for the echo (or just expect "\n")
sleep 4
puts "text"
expect "output of ssh (next prompt)" {...}
```

To wait for the echo of that cmd first. Or:

```
send "cmd\r"
sleep 4
expect "output of ssh (next prompt)" {puts "text"; ...}
```

Where the `text` is then displayed upon the next prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flush the output file. After each `puts` add the line

```
 flush stdout
```

See the tcl [flush](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/flush.htm) command. Alternatively, you can set the output to non-buffered mode with a single line:

```
 fconfigure stdout -buffering none
```

See tcl [fconfigure](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.2.3/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm).

Comment: I resolved the issue with including the puts in {} after expect and it worked. But I will look into your explanation also. thanks.